# Unable to fetch UUID based record from H2DB in Postgresql mode

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data, h2

I have a spring boot application with H2DB with Postgresql mode. Created table with auto generated UUID as primary key. This primary key will be created from DB side (H2) upon inserting a row.

I can able to insert rows successfully using JPA and its creating UUID based rows. But with that generated UUID when I write sql i am getting data type in compatible error in H2 console.

Also when I access the particular row using UUID using Data JPA empty row is getting returned.

Below is my code snippet.

```
//Schema.sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  tb_user  (
    id UUID DEFAULT UUID() PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    last_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    date_of_birth DATE,
    gender VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    created_date TIMESTAMP,
    modified_date TIMESTAMP
);

@Entity
@Table
public class UserEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue //Let the underlying DB take care of UUID creation.
    private UUID id;
}


select * from TB_USER where ID = '4a147611-5a7e-492f-8b65-a05316bd5a85'; //Given UUID value was generated by JPA successfuly.

When execute this query H2 console is giving below error.

Values of types "BINARY(255)" and "CHARACTER VARYING(36)" are not comparable; SQL statement:
select * from TB_USER where ID = '4a147611-5a7e-492f-8b65-a05316bd5a85' [90110-214] 90110/90110 (Help)

Also trying to access the this row from JPA with repository getting null back.

UserEntity findUserEntityById(UUID id); // This is my Repository method.
```

Comment: This exception indicates that `TB_USER.ID` column actually has incorrect `BINARY(255)` data type instead of `UUID` data type (supported by both PostgreSQL and H2), so your custom table definition wasn't actually used.

Comment: @EvgenijRyazanov I can able to see the record got inserted properly with id value in H2. But your mentioning my Create table script UUID type was not applied instead that table was created with ID column as BINARY(255)?

Comment: You can insert a character string into `BINARY(255)` column, but you can't compare a character string with a `BINARY(255)` column in H2. Use `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none` setting or add `@Column(columnDefinition = "UUID")` annotation to your column.